# tests/integration/test_lottery_integration.py:17: ValueError

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I get the following error when running my test:

```
def test_can_pick_winner():
        if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
            pytest.skip()
        lottery = deploy_lottery()
        account = get_account()
        lottery.startLottery({"from": account})
        lottery.enter({"from": account, "value": lottery.getEntranceFee()})
        lottery.enter({"from": account, "value": lottery.getEntranceFee()})
        fund_with_link
>       lottery.endLottery({"from": account})
E       ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.

tests/integration/test_lottery_integration.py:17: ValueError
============================================================================================================= short test summary info ==============================================================================================================
FAILED tests/integration/test_lottery_integration.py::test_can_pick_winner - ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
```

Any clue on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I change vrf_coordinator = '0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B' and verify = false in brownie-config.yaml file. Because this is address of vrf-contract version 1 https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/v1/. This worked for me!